# ticking checkboxes using mechanize

Tags: javascript, html, perl, mechanize

I have the following html piece from this website: 
http://catalogue.bl.uk/F/NTBK6NCP3LK56BPNU2NJ4FF4MBLIRUNMFX66JLHKBDV1RNCAAB-02920?func=short-0&set_number=151530

```
<form name="XXX000001" method="GET"><input type="checkbox" name="ckbox"   onclick="javascript:select_record(this.form);" onkeypressed="javascript:select_record(this.form);"></form>
```

I was wondering if there is anyway I can use mechanize to tick the checkboxes? It seems that these boxes are not formed using the normal html. I don't know javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should check [WWW::Selenium](http://search.cpan.org/~mattp/Test-WWW-Selenium-1.25/lib/WWW/Selenium.pm) in order to deal with JavaScript web pages.

`WWW::Selenium` is a kind of remote control for browsers.
From the documentation: *Selenium Remote Control (SRC) is a test tool that allows you to write automated web application UI tests in any programming language against any HTTP website using any mainstream JavaScript-enabled browser.
SRC provides a Selenium Server, which can automatically start/stop/control any supported browser. It works by using Selenium Core, a pure-HTML+JS library that performs automated tasks in JavaScript; the Selenium Server communicates directly with the browser using AJAX (XmlHttpRequest).*

After you have downloaded and installed the Selenium server ( a Java apllication ), you can use the module `WWW::Seletion`, to control the server which will use browsers to interact with complex JavaScript enabled web sites.

With an instance of the class `WWW::Selenium`

```
my $sel = WWW::Selenium->new(
    host => "localhost",
    port => 4444,
    browser => "*iexplore",
    browser_url => "http://www.google.com",
);
```

almost every kind of interaction with a web site become possible. One has to define a *locator* to pinpoint an element in the page, in order to issue a command ( select, click, ... ).

You'll find detailed help in the module documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about submitting information back to the page using Mechanize as if a human was using a browser to tick the checkboxes.  The easiest way to do this is to first use WireShark to watch everything that happens when you actually submit the form with a web browser (with the checkboxes checked) and then mimic that same behavior when you submit the form using Perl.

Answer (score 1):

Because WWW::Mechanize does not speak javascript, you either need to do as suggested and figure out what the javascript does and go around its back or you can use something like [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox) that will allow you to control a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion that is admittedly not the most elegant solution but in the spirit of "gett'r done" you could try and create an [autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) script that did some of the gui interactions for you. It is pretty neat little tool. I was bored of leveling my character in a  game once so I created an autoit script to level my player for me and it only took me about a day to learn the syntax and create the script. I am sure automating a webpage would take much, much less time. Just a thought...